# I changed power steering fluid and it keeps making noise and is bubbles

Tags: power-steering

I am trying my first time to flush the power steering fluid on my 2003 Infinity Q45.

This is the procedure I have followed:

Disconnect return hose to the power steering fluid tank.

Drain power steering fluid from tank.

Refill tank with new power steering fluid. I use AMSOIL ATFQT. It is recommended on their website.

Turn steering wheel very fast and lightly touch each stop.

Refill tank as necessary.

Stop when clean fluid comes out of return hose.

One problem I made was one time I emptied the tank on accident after turning the wheel too many times, so I just refilled and keep going.

After this I started the car and the pump makes a lot of noise, so I turn it off.

The two problem I made was that now a bunch of bubbly ATF is coming out of the tank.

So now I also notice in the bottom of the manual it states to bleed the system using this procedure:

Turn wheel back and forth quickly and lightly touch each stop, watching fluid level. So I keep track and the fluid level does drop lower than the tank cap can measure, so I put more fluid in until it is in the cold range and not lowering any more.

I turn the engine on and the pump makes a bunch of noise. I turn the engine off and the tank is overflowing again with bubbles.

After some time the bubbles go away and the oil returns to prvious level.

I am wondering if Amsoil recommends the wrong fluid or if I am doing something wrong or maybe I break something?

Answer (score 4):

One of the first things to consider is the aeration of fluid. A better way to 'bleed' the system is to fill the reservoir to its full mark, and allow the engine to idle. Top up the fluid as it drops in level. When the fluid level stabilises, SLOWLY turn the steering wheel lock to lock, topping up any fluid drop if it drops. The pump noises you are hearing, assuming they were not there before you started the flush, is air trapped in the system. Slow operaration is the key until the flush is completed, fast and furious operation during the flush only goes to aerate the fluid.

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this is, if possible, suspend the front tires off the ground during the procedure. This takes nearly all of the pressure off of the power steering components, which helps prevent any damage to the system in case of low fluid during the exchange. Once all the noise and bubbles are gone, drop the front end down and top off the fluids to an operating level.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same thing.  It kept making noise and I noticed it was bubbling a bit in the reservoir.  I let it idle and made small turns back and forth and while the engine was running sort of kept gently jiggling the reservoir and the inlet and outflow lines.  After about 10 minutes the noise went away.  I carefully drove around the blocks in the neighborhood and all is well and the steering is noticeably smoother now.

Answer (score 1):

This is reasonably common and nothing to worry about, If you have turned the wheel lock to lock a few times and re-filled with fluid you have done everything right.

The fluid is just too aerated, leave it over night and start the car back up and it should be fine. Sounds too simply but I've come across this issue a dozen times.